# Algorithm of searching minimal distance between sequences of points

Tags: algorithm

I have a sequence of points(searched), length is n. Point is a pair of numbers (a,b) like x and y coordinates. And I have a huge massive of another sequences of points that have randomly length. And the task is find m sequences from huge massive that have minimal distance to searched sequence. Distance will be minimal when sum of closest points is minimal even than searched sequence is longer.

Comment: If possible, please make your question more descriptive... more people then, will be able to take a shot at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a k-means based clustering approach to minimize squared distances between points for a given N number of clusters.

Comment: You might want to try this example Xcode project, it does kmeans clustering: https://github.com/mdejong/DivQuantCluster

Answer (score 0):

You could model the question as a weighted graph G = (V, E, f) such that a node in the graph is a point and the weighting function f for each edge between two adjacent points is the intermediate distance between those points.

Then you can just run [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) on the graph of points that you created which will calculate the shortest path from the starting node to any point reachable in the graph. You are interested in the shortest path tree so that if you are wanting to find the shortest path to a specific point you can just get the point and follow it's previous pointers to get it's shortest path from the starting point.